# How add a ticker in the Pine script

Tags: pine-script

How add an entry to receive BTC futures data.

PS It was not possible to contact the owner of the script, so I turn to the experts.

Here is the code itself.

```
    study("William's Commercial Index", shorttitle="WILLCO", precision=2)
force_root = input("", title="Override Product")
is_includeoptions = input(false, type=bool, title="Include Options")


fxroot =
      
      ticker == "USDRUB" ? "RU" : 
      ticker == "USDSEK" ? "SE" : 
      ticker == "USDZAR" ? "RA" : 
      ticker == "EURUSD" ? "EC" : 
      ticker == "AUDUSD" ? "AD" : 
      ticker == "GBPUSD" ? "BP" : 
      ticker == "NZDUSD" ? "NE" : 
      ticker == "BRLUSD" ? "BR" : 
      ""
root = force_root == "" ? fxroot == "" ? syminfo.root : fxroot : force_root
code = root + (is_includeoptions ? "_FO_L_ALL" : "_F_L_ALL")

is_inversed = 
      
      ticker == "USDNOK" ? true : 
      ticker == "USDPLN" ? true : 
      ticker == "USDRUB" ? true : 
      ticker == "USDSEK" ? true : 
      ticker == "USDZAR" ? true : 
      false

long_total = security("QUANDL:CFTC/"+code+"|4", "D", close)
short_total = close
oi = security("QUANDL:CFTC/"+code+"|0", "D", close)

long = is_inversed ? short_total : long_total
short = is_inversed ? long_total : short_total
net = long-short
willco = net / oi

length = input(24, title="Period (weeks)")

max = highest(willco, length)
min = lowest(willco, length)
index = 100 * (willco - min) / (max - min)

index_adopted = security("QUANDL:CFTC/"+code+"|5", "D", index)

plot(index_adopted, color = black, title="Index", style=line)
hline(80, color=blue, linestyle=dashed)
hline(20, color=blue, linestyle=dashed)
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line at the top under study line,

symbolName = input(title="Symbol", type=symbol, defval="BTCUSDTPERP")

Comment: Thank you, the tool is being added, but apparently this is not exactly what I need. 
1. The indicator does not display anything.
2. Apparently it should receive data from QUANDL (it seems to me so :))